# How can I install gcc version 4 in debian?

Tags: linux, gcc, debian, version

I have to install gcc version 4, but when I try the following line:

`apt-get install gcc-4`

I get:

`E: unable to locate package gcc-4`

I can install the last version just with:

`apt-get install gcc`

But that's not what I want

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think that it shows a specific problem